# How to create a generic number of objects?

Tags: java, object

I am currently thinking about how to create n objects of type x in Java.

 Thought experiment: You want to create all entries from a specific database table as an object.

 The number of entries are given by counting them.

 The object to be created is a model of a table entry.

My current strategy would be to create Lists foreach column.
After that, I would create an Object by looping through the Lists, append it to a HashSet and continue with the next row.
But probably there is a problem with the references, because the created objects would have the same name and if I remember right, I would overwrite the pointer by creating another object in this case. So it's the question if the HashSet still contains the old reference or not.

Besides this solution would be very ineffective cause of the number of loops.

```
Pseudocode

HashSet for objects
lists of every column

iterate through lists
 create object with values at position i of loop
 append object to HashSet
```

If you have a clue about to solve the pointer problem or if it does not exist, I would be glad about your answer. Moreover, I would be grateful for more suited solutions.

PS: I did not found any design pattern for this use case

Comment: "You want to create all entries from a specific database table as an object." <- If that is your actual use case, you should rather have a look at JPA / Hibernate or other ORM database frameworks in java, because this is like the most basic use case for them.

Comment: 1. I don't get what it has to do with generics. 2. What pointers are you talking about? Java doesn't have pointers. 3. HashSet uses `equals()` to decide uniqueness of elements.

Comment: I will look JPA and Hibernate up, thanks. Maybe I used the wrong term, I do not mean pointers like c++ pointers, I am writing about the Java references, I was taught to use the term pointer for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm correctly understanding the "pointer problem" to which you refer, **it does not exist.**  I think you may have some misconceptions about how **references**, as they are properly called in Java, work.

Take the following code

```
Set<MyObject> mySet = new HashSet<>();
MyObject myOb;

myOb = new MyObject("Object #1");   // 1
mySet.add(myOb);                    // 2
myOb = new MyObject("Object #2");   // 3
mySet.add(myOb);                    // 4
```

At the lines marked `// 1` and `// 2` we create a `MyObject` object with the data `"Object #"` and add it into a `Set`; the variable `myOb` references the object we've just created.

If we were to print the contents of the set at this point, we'd see

```
{["Object #1"]}
```

At line `// 3`, we create another new `MyObject` object, this time with the data `"Object #2"`, and assign `myOb` to reference it.

*But wait!*  We've just added `myOb` (which was referencing an object with the data "Object #1") to the set, and now we're changing `myOb` to reference a different object.  Does that mean our set suddenly looks like:

```
{["Object 2"]}
```

**No, it doesn't**, because what was added to the set was not `myOb` itself, but the rather the `myObject` object that `myOb` happened to be referencing at the moment that `mySet.add(myOb)` was called.  All the set received was a reference to a `MyObject` instance; it hasn't the slightest clue that the reference happened to be stored in the variable `myOb`.

Thus we can make `myOb` reference (or "point to", if you prefer) any other `MyObject` object (or even the same object again) without affecting the set in the slightest.